# SQL Convert Table row to Full XML with Special Characters

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, escaping, character

I need to create XML from a table row and put it into a field.  I'm currently using this:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), Address VARCHAR(20), Phone VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @x VALUES ('Ben & Eileen Dover','5 Curdsan Way','123-456-7890')

select [MyField] = (
   select *
   from @x
   for xml path('Customer'), TYPE
)
```

However, that converts the `&` symbol into `&amp;`.  Is there any way to translate special characters without having to do a REPLACE for every one?  I tried using the (XML).value('.','varchar(max)') trick, but that removes the element names.  The field needs to contain the complete XML (it's being passed to a service).

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: Changed the tags according to the given code. Please check this and correct if necessary...

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely necessary to escape some characters in order to create well-formed XML. Especially `<, > and &` are candidates.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), Address VARCHAR(20), Phone VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @x VALUES ('Ben & Eileen Dover','5 Curdsan Way','123-456-7890')

DECLARE @xml XML=
(
   select *
   from @x
   for xml path('Customer'), TYPE
);
```

This is the resulting XML

```
<Customer>
  <Name>Ben &amp; Eileen Dover</Name>
  <Address>5 Curdsan Way</Address>
  <Phone>123-456-7890</Phone>
</Customer>
```

If you'd replace the `&amp;` to get something like `<Name>Ben & Eileen Dover</Name>` your XML will not be readable anymore.

But all these characters are re-escaped implicitly. Try it out:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Customer/Name/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS Name
      ,@xml.value('(/Customer/Address/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS Address
      ,@xml.value('(/Customer/Phone/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS Phone

Name                Address         Phone
Ben & Eileen Dover  5 Curdsan Way   123-456-7890
```

Comment: And: `&amp;` in XML will be rendered as `&`. Also XML APIs will retrieve text values again as `&`.